# Monotouch objective C Bindings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I have included some controls from "Cocoa Controls" in our project using mono bindings and they all work fine except there is one I cant get working I was hoping someone could spot an obvious mistake.

here is the objective C header

```
typedef enum {
kWTShort = 1,
kWTLong = 5
} WToastLength;

@interface WToast : UIView

+ (void)showWithText:(NSString *)text;
+ (void)showWithImage:(UIImage *)image;


+ (void)showWithText:(NSString *)text length:(WToastLength)length textColor:(UIColor *)    textColor backgroundColor:(UIColor *) backGroundColor;
+ (void)showWithImage:(UIImage *)image length:(WToastLength)length;



@end
```

and here is the Mono ApiDefinition

```
[BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
interface WToast
{
      [Export("showWithText:")]
       void ShowText(String text);


    [Export("showWithText:length:textColor:backgroundColor:")]
    void ShowText(string text,ToastLenght lenght,UIColor textColor,UIColor   backgroundColor);
}
```

note I have not included the enum ToastLength

any way the object instantiates but when I call ShowText the program cant find the selector [WToast showWithText:]

I hope someone can help

regards Christian Stœr Andersen

Answer (score 3):

I think I just needed to walk away from the code for a bit.

the answer is that I am a bit thick

You will notice that the objective c function is

```
+ (void)showWithText:(NSString *)text;
```

not

```
- (void)showWithText:(NSString *)text;
```

there for the Mono definition should be

```
[Static,Export("showWithText:")]
   void ShowText(String text);
```

not

```
[Export("showWithText:")]
   void ShowText(String text);
```

Thanks All